# gnome-settings-daemon flickering ghost window

Tags: gnome, gnome-settings-daemon

In Ubuntu 12.04, when I login through `lightdm`, a "ghost" window appears. This window does not show any content. Instead it flickers its borders and move down vertically.

When I `xprop` it, it reports to be `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-settings-daemon", "Gnome-settings-daemon"`.

I can get rid of the flickering ghost window by twice killing it:

```
killall -9 gnome-settings-daemon
killall -9 gnome-settings-daemon
```

This stops the flickering window.

Restarting `gnome-settings-daemon` from the terminal I do not get a flickering window, but my `.xsession-errors` file reports:

```
failed to create drawable
compiz (core) - Warn: glXCreatePixmap failed
compiz (core) - Warn: Couldn't bind background pixmap 0x3e00001 to texture
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
```

Previous errors in `.xsession-errors` are:

```
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
compiz (opengl) - Info: Couldn't bind redirected window 0xa0000b to texture
```

What is happening?